# How to manage display block and display none on basis of parent Class is <a class="active">link</a>

Tags: css

```
<div class="set">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="active">TEST <img class="" src="/active-arrow.svg">
    </a>
    <div class="content">content </div>
```

I want to set css for content class.
if  { display: block}.
else { display: none;}

if tried

```
.set > a.active {
  color: #123399;
  font-family: 'lato-bold'; }

.content {
  display: none; }

.set > a.active .content{
    display: block;}
```

but not getting the proper results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) `+`.

```css
a.active + .content {
   display: block;
}
```

> The `+` combinator **selects adjacent siblings**. This means that the second element directly follows the first, and both share the same parent.
> source: [CSS selectors - CSS: Cascading Style Sheets | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Combinators)

---

#### Example

```js
const toggleActive = (btn) => {
console.log(btn.classList.contains("active"));
  btn.classList.contains("active")
    ? btn.classList.remove("active")
    : btn.classList.add("active")
}
```

```css
.content {
  display: none; 
}
a.active + .content{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="set">
  <a class="active" onClick="toggleActive(this)">TEST</a>
  <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
```